# tell ONLY from the view if a scope variable is a function or not?

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way in an angular view to do:

```
{{ foo() || foo }}
```

I am looking for an easy way to have a reusable view that multiple controllers can use which can support using either a variable or a function.  I am not interested in doing scope.isFunction = angular.isFunction, or anything like that....

I was hoping I could just do `ng-if="foo()"` and `ng-if="!foo()"`, but all I get from that is an error about calling '0' on null.

Comment: The view is not supposed to make such checks. You're going down a messy road with this.

Comment: "foo() || foo" is a mesy road???  The point of this question is to find a way to be able to have one view work for multiple controllers without having to have a bunch of dumb and un-necessarily duplicated logic.  Sorry...  In my opinion it's a flaw in angular to now allow such a simple fallback.

Comment: Controllers have better ways to share logic with each other, namely services, without having to resort to relying on a template for this.

Comment: If I had to choose between being able to write "foo() || foo" vs. 1) write test code for a service 2) write real code for the service 3) inject and make user of the service in the controllers, I think I would prefer "foo() || foo"

Comment: Others would choose to avoid the ambiguity in the argument type altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a filter:

HTML:

```
{{ someValue | maybeFunc }}
```

JS:

```
app.filter('maybeFunc', function() {
  return function(v) {
    if (typeof v === 'function') return v();
    return v;
  };
});
```

[Example on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dny5KQ4CPn4F5NgfThi0)

Comment: this is such a bummer.  filters are wasteful, slow, and require more code.  why oh why can't angular just evaluate the function and null from the function and fallback to the next value?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to solve. If you need to use a function, may as well just always use a function.